# Using th:each with Themeleaf and applying partitioning on empty list throw error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Iterating over list of hotel. whenever list is empty its giving me error

```
     <div class="row list" th:if="${#lists.size(hotels) > 0}" th:each="hotelChunk : ${T(com.google.common.collect.Lists).partition(hotels, ${#lists.size(hotels)})}">
                <!-- single result item -->
                <div th:each="hotel : ${hotelChunk}"  class="col-md-4 single-result" >
```

Error is :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "T(com.google.common.collect.Lists).partition(hotels, ${#lists.size(hotels)})" (search:44)
```

Any work around is there for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `th:each` to:

```
th:each="hotelChunk : ${T(com.google.common.collect.Lists).partition(hotels, #lists.size(hotels))}"
```

There is no need to use `${..}` again inside a current Thymeleaf expression.

Comment: i copied and paste your changes  but getting same error

Comment: Error is : HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "T(com.google.common.collect.Lists).partition(hotels, #lists.size(hotels))"

Comment: Are you using cache? Clean & restart?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I am not using any cache. but still clear it and run it again . got same error . I think its issue with expression T(com.google.common.collect.Lists).partition(hotels, #lists.size(hotels))"       but couldn't figure out yet.

Comment: It's strange, could you try to put a fix number as the size? Ie (4 as the size of the list): T(com.google.common.collect.Lists).partition(hotels,4)

Comment: statement will work T(com.google.common.collect.Lists).partition(hotels,4)  but if i put "0" in place of "4" it throws error.That's the basic issue. whenever list size become 0 it throws error. T(com.google.common.collect.Lists).partition(hotels,0) will throw error.

Comment: Ok, great, the problem then is related to attribute precedence (http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence), extract the th:if in a div outside and test again.